# Can I fade / animate the tintColor of a UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitoolbar, tintcolor

I am trying to animate a UIToolbar's tintColor property, to change it from one tintColor to another.

Here is the code I am trying. Unfortunately, the change occurs immediately and does not fade from green to blue. This is strange because I know Apple fades and "pulses" toolbar tint colors when tethering or on a phone call. So why doesn't this work?

```
// set initial tint color  
myBottomToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.95 blue:0.15 alpha:0.6];

//animation stuff  
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.95];  
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];        

//thing to animate  
myBottomToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.35 blue:0.45 alpha:0.6];

//animation stuff  
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Try pasting your code via the binary button in the WSYIWYG editor.  That way it keeps its formatting.

Comment: A decade later .. You now just use **.tintAdjustmentMode** for this.

Answer (score 4):

The tint color in not animatable through public APIs. You can work around this by manually changing the tint color on a timer. You would have to interpolate the intermediate color levels.

Comment: .tintAdjustmentMode is now available

Answer (score 2):

Each `UIView` has a [tintAdjustmentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622555-tintadjustmentmode):

> The first non-default tint adjustment mode value in the view’s
>   hierarchy, ascending from and starting with the view itself.
>
> When this property’s value is dimmed, the value of the tintColor property is modified to provide a dimmed appearance.

For example, if you need to dim the current tintColor (dim = grey color) just use the code below:

```
// Assuming tintAdjustmentMode is set to .automatic
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   yourView.tintAdjustmentMode = .dimmed
}
```

This will animate the tintColor to grey and will dim it.

If you want to animate the tintColor to your own custom color:

```
// Make sure it is set to normal and not automatic
yourView.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   yourView.tintColor = .black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here's my somewhat hasty solution for animating tint. I'm sure there are  more clever ways of doing this with categories and a struct for the rgb values yadda yadda.  I was in a hurry, OK?!

**UITabBarController subclass:**

```
@interface BaseNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    NSTimer *           tintTimer;
    UIColor *           targetColor;
}

-(void)changeTintTo:(UIColor*)color;
-(void)animateTint;
```

.

```
-(void)changeTintTo:(UIColor*)color;
{
    targetColor = [color retain];

    [tintTimer invalidate];
    tintTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(animateTint) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)animateTint;
{
    UIColor * currentColor = self.navigationBar.tintColor;

    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [currentColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

    CGFloat targetRed, targetGreen, targetBlue, targetAlpha;
    [targetColor getRed:&targetRed green:&targetGreen blue:&targetBlue alpha:&targetAlpha];

    CGFloat newRed = red + ((targetRed - red)*.2);

    UIColor * newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:newRed
                                         green:green + ((targetGreen - green)*.2)
                                          blue:blue + ((targetBlue - blue)*.2) // the .2 adjusts the fade speed
                                         alpha:1.0];

    if(
       (newRed < targetRed && newRed >= targetRed-0.01) || 
       (newRed > targetRed && newRed <= targetRed+0.01)
    )
    {
        newColor = targetColor;
        [targetColor autorelease];
        [tintTimer invalidate];
        tintTimer = nil;
        targetColor = nil;
    }

    self.navigationBar.tintColor = newColor;

}
```

Comment: You should use `CADisplayLink` rather than an `NSTimer` for animations.

Comment: just use .tintAdjustmentMode

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` and it's setup is a lot of work for a simple animation. Here's my solution using dispatch, I'm just fading a `UIBarButtonItem` in and out by changing the alpha value of the tint color:

```
-(void)animateItemToTargetAlpha:(CGFloat)targetAlpha
{
    static dispatch_source_t timer = nil;
    static CGFloat DURATION = 0.25f;
    static CGFloat FPS = 30.f;
dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
    timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1/FPS * NSEC_PER_SEC,(1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);

    CGFloat red, green, blue, __block alpha;
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{
        alpha = targetAlpha == 1.0f ? alpha + (1/(FPS * DURATION)) : alpha - (1/(FPS * DURATION));
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
        if(alpha >= 1 || alpha  <= 0)
        {
            dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
        }
    });

    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
```

The linear curve can be a little noticeable but I'm interested in trying CADisplayLink first before making any changes.