# UI Animation using animateKeyframes does nothing to Button Title Color

Tags: swift, uianimation

I'm trying to animate the color of my *UIButton* **Title Color** using *animateKeyframes* but it does nothing except load the last state in the animation, in this case purpleText. I'm using the same code to animate button colors and a UIView background color without any issues.

I checked also changed the button to a *custom button* in *Interface Builder* but that didn't help either.

```
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 12, delay: 12, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(blueText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.2, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(greenText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(yellowText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.6, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(redText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.8, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(purpleText, for: UIControlState.normal)
            })
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setTitleColor()` inside the animation block doesn't work because `UIView.animate` only works on animatable properties, like `infoButton.backgroundColor`.

Unfortunately, button properties like `tintColor` [aren't animatable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673229/14351818). You also shouldn't directly access the button's `titleLabel`, which is `nil` for system buttons.

Instead, you can use `UIView.transition` with `setTitleColor()`. You can then put it inside a `Timer`... I usually don't like to use timers for animations, but I can't think of any other way.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [.blue, .green, .yellow, .red, .purple]
    var currentIndex = 0
    
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
        if colors.indices.contains(currentIndex) {
            UIView.transition(with: self.infoButton, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .allowUserInteraction]) {
                self.infoButton.setTitleColor(colors[currentIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            currentIndex += 1
        } else {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Button title color animates and cycles]

Comment: Alternative to `Timer` is to create a function for the animation and then call it with `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`.

For example:
`self.perform(#selector(self.myAnimationFunction), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform