# Strange UIView.animate behavior changing UIButton title color

Tags: ios, swift, animation, optimization, uibutton

**Question**

I am trying to animate a UIView color from light grey to dark grey and a UIButton title color from blue to orange.

The animation is meant to take place over 3 seconds when the UIButton is tapped.

The UIView changes color over 3 seconds, but the UIButton does not, and instantly changes color.

- Why is the UIButton title color animation not working as intended?
- How do I get the animation to work specifically using UIView.animate?

Thank you.

---

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set view colour
        self.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        // Set initial title color
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 50)
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        // Add tap gesture recognizer to trigger animation
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        
        // Animate the change of view and title color
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            self.button.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .normal)
        })
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate UIButton's title change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231947/animate-uibuttons-title-change)

Comment: Thanks. I did try `.transition` and that works but was hoping `.animate` would work too, keeping animation items neat and together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling setTitleColor(_:for:) method of UIButton does not animate the color change because it's not animatable. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67323728/8263578.

If you are okay without UIView.animate method, you can use this code block:

```
// Animate the change of button title color
UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
    self.button.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .normal)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I did try `.transition` and that works but was hoping `.animate` would work too, keeping animation items neat and together.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this on buttonTapped() function:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    })
    
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
    self.button.setTitleColor(.orange, for: .normal)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but `.animate` does not work on `setTitleColor`. See above `.transition` alternative approach.